# CDI stops working when using weld-se-core and weld-servlet-core?

Tags: java, cdi, jboss-weld

I am playing with Weld-SE. I have a project which has pluggable modules. With one module, weld works. When other module, which uses `weld-servlet-core`, is put on classpath (with it's deps), CDI stops working, giving errors like "Unable to resolve dependency XY" or (after removing that `@Inject`) this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001417 Enabled interceptor class <class>org.jboss.weld.environment.se.jpa.JpaTransactionInterceptor</class> in jar:file:/mnt/ssd1/data/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jawabot/JawaBot-core/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/JawaBot-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml@11 is neither annotated @Interceptor nor registered through a portable extension
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateEnabledInterceptorClasses(Validator.java:466)
    ...
```

Although the class has `@Interceptor` (and the same class works fine with the other module).

When I debug `WeldBootstrap#startContainer(Environment environment, Deployment deployment)`,
`deployment.beanDeploymentArchive.beanClasses` contains the interceptor
(`"org.jboss.weld.environment.se.jpa.JpaTransactionInterceptor"`).

I've checked the dependencies and TattleTale report, they all seem fine.

Any ideas what should I look at / try next?

The project is at http://ondrazizka.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bots/JawaBot/branches/2.0/ To see the error, run mvn dependency:copy-dependencies java -cp ... org.jboss.jawabot.JawaBotApp Or simply run the web module in NetBeans.

Thanks, Ondra

***Update:*** JIRA: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-940
Also, I found that it might be caused by a bug in Weld's scanning extension, `<weld:scan>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by using Weld's scanning extension, `<weld:scan>`:

An `<includes>` element contained package wildcard which resulted in matching classes in both "packages" (which is .jar in CDI / Weld's terminology IIUC).

I am not sure if I used it improperly or it's a bug.
See JIRA: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-940